# Up to date tutorial for writing Compiz plugins?

Tags: compiz

A quick Google search reveals very few tutorials on writing Compiz plugins and even fewer seem to be up to date. None that I can find are written specifically for Ubuntu.

I basically need to know:

- What packages I will need.
- How plugins are stored / organized.
- How plugin code should be structured.
- How to use CMake with my plugin.

Comment: I presume you have read the recent dev week where Sam Spillaz talked through just this topic? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MeetingLogs/devweek1103/HowToWriteACompizPlugin

Comment: @foss: No, that did not show up in any of my searches. I will gladly upvote that if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sam Spillaz (Canonical's key-developer Compiz development) recently held a session in the Developer's week held in March '11 headlined "[How to write a Compiz Plugin](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MeetingLogs/devweek1103/HowToWriteACompizPlugin)"

This session took attendees through the following topics:

1. recent compiz development
2. how to compile on ubuntu
3. basic structure of compiz plugin code
4. walk through on a basic compiz plugin development.

Its well worth a read and I hope to see your efforts soon in some great plugins.  Well done!